# Show path to a dll in a MessageBox husing handle

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I load a dll with this command

```
HINSTANCE DllEconovent = LoadLibrary(_T("Econovent.dll"));
```

I want to get the path from where the dll is loaded from disk... In this fake case

```
C:\TFS_FWG\Acon\Oem\bin\Econovent.20140130_3200\Econovent64\Econovent.dll
```

And just show it with message box

```
MessageBox(_T("No valid ProcAddress"), _T("Error"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

How is this done in the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx): this function "retrieves the fully qualified path for the file that contains the specified module."

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileName(
  _In_opt_  HMODULE hModule,
  _Out_     LPTSTR lpFilename,
  _In_      DWORD nSize
);
```

It should take in your `HINSTANCE` object and give you back a filename.

---

## A simple example

```
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE test = LoadLibrary("test.dll");
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(test, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Adapting it to the `MessageBox`, just remove the line with `std::cout` and put

```
MessageBox(buffer, _T("Error"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Comment: Please use MAX_PATH, 255 is not a happy number.